# How to close correctly an Android app using XE5?

Tags: android, forms, delphi

My app have two forms. fLogin and fMain. The default form is fLogin. The user types login and password and click an OK button. Then the main form shows. I´d like to close the fLogin because that form is not necessary anymore. If the user press the back button of the mobile device the app turns to show the fLogin. I've tried the codes "Self.Close" after login and before fMain show, "Application.Terminate" on the onClose event of the fMain, but without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **finish()** command. I use it like that:

```
application.getActivity().finish();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'ts necessary add some unit in the uses section?